# Ember.js' getting started snippet duplicates template for each navigation

Tags: ember.js

I've been learning about Ember lately and I've been playing around with the examples in the guide section of their website, and I'm having problems with the following snippets:

1) Javascript

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') +
           " " + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var people = [
      App.Person.create({
        firstName: "Tom",
        lastName: "Dale"
      }),
      App.Person.create({
        firstName: "Yehuda",
        lastName: "Katz"
      })
    ];
    return people;
  }
});
```

2) HTML

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h1>People</h1>

  <ul>
  {{#each model}}
    <li>Hello, <b>{{fullName}}</b>!</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

When I navigate to the website, it correctly shows the page and the names as expected. Then I navigate to localhost:80/#, and it duplicates the template so that everything is showed twice. When I navigate back and forth using the browser's arrow controls, the template is appended/copied every time at the bottom of the page.

I honestly cannot understand why it does that. Ideas?

Comment: I put the example into a JSBin and it seems to work: http://jsbin.com/ixupad/322/edit

Comment: I did mention that it worked. The weird behavior is when I navigate.

Comment: can it be re-created in that jsbin?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to navigate in jsbin.

Comment: if you drop the `/edit` part you can directly access the page: http://jsbin.com/ixupad/322

Comment: Ahhhh cool. And yes, the error occurs on jsbin. Add a /# at the end of the url, and navigate there. Then press the back arrow. Then forward. Then back. And the content will be copied over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model hook is kicked off when you hit a route w/ the dynamic segment, something like the below is more ember-esk

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') +
           " " + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
}).reopenClass({
  people: [],
  find: function() {
    this.people.clear(); //so find doesn't create duplicates each time
    var first = App.Person.create({ firstName: "Tom", lastName: "Dale" });
    var last = App.Person.create({ firstName: "Yehuda", lastName: "Katz" });
    this.people.pushObject(first);
    this.people.pushObject(last);
    return this.people;
  }
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Person.find();
  }
});
```

Also you don't usually work with a "model" from the base application template/view/controller/route so it might make more sense to create a simple model and have that route do the find() instead (to avoid the duplicate issue you are running into)

Comment: There was another solution that was posted on the related discussion thread on emberjs.com, which talked about using Application.IndexRoute instead. What's your take on that?

Comment: hard to say -that wasn't posted here :)

Comment: I posted his answer here for future reference.

Comment: I think the point about re-entry is valid and good from the response you posted, but I still think it's worth mentioning that you never work with "models" from the application route itself (and might be why you felt this pain to begin with). instead application is just a "starting point" of sorts. From here I would have created a people route / controller / view / template that deals with the model directly (leaving application route / view unaware of the model state)

Answer (score 1):

There was another suggestion posted on the Ember.js [**discussion forums**](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/getting-started-snippet-question/851/2). Credit to user teddyzeenny.

> Returning a model in the application route is causing a re-render. It's better to use IndexRoute instead of ApplicationRoute.

1) Javascript

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') +
           " " + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var people = [
      App.Person.create({
        firstName: "Tom",
        lastName: "Dale"
      }),
      App.Person.create({
        firstName: "Yehuda",
        lastName: "Katz"
      })
    ];
    return people;
  }
});
```

2) HTML

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  <h1>People</h1>

  <ul>
  {{#each model}}
    <li>Hello, <b>{{fullName}}</b>!</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

More discussion in the pull request he made:

> Returning a model in ApplicationRoute might cause the application
>   template to re-render in some cases ([as mentioned here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/getting-started-snippet-question/851/2)).
>
> The application template should never re-render because it is appended
>   to the body, therefore causing a duplicate template on re-render.
>
> This PR also adds an {{outlet}}, and since some people are using this
>   example as a starting point, having an outlet ready will make it
>   easier for them to build on the example.